# Emacs ruby-mode, indenting wildly inside parentheses?

Tags: ruby, emacs

Excuse my emacs newbiness here, but does anybody know how to get around this?  When coding in emacs, in ruby-mode, it indents to the correct level (i.e. by 2 spaces) after all the keywords, like `def`, `class`, `module`, `begin` etc, but when breaking parameter lists across multiple lines, it indents to a seemingly random position, like 40 or so columns over.

I've been reading around emacs tab settings and seem to just be going around in circles and not getting to information I'm looking for, so I figured I'd ask here.

Here's a screenshot of where it is placing the cursor in a parameter list.  I've tried indenting inside of curly braces (e.g. for a block, or a hash) and that is working ok, it's the parentheses that are messing it up.

[image: Bug]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://compgroups.net/comp.emacs/Ruby-mode-indentation-of-continuation-lines

```
(setq ruby-deep-indent-paren nil)
```

Or temporarily, within the current session:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> set-variable <kbd>RET</kbd> ruby-deep-indent-paren <kbd>RET</kbd> nil <kbd>RET</kbd>

Inside of a parentheses it will now indent like it does everywhere else.  There is still a *minor* bug in the case of what I posted above.  It indents 2 spaces further than I want it to, because I'm confusing it with the combination of `(` and `{`.

Comment: One minor flaw remains: Closing parentheses/brackets are still mistakenly indented flush with the contents, rather than flush with the expression that opened the list.

Comment: @mcandre did you ever figure out how to fix that?

Comment: No, sadly. I would have posted as soon as I found a fix.

Comment: @mcandre while researching the actual ruby norms for a separate stackoverflow question, I stumbled across this. i'm guessing we were both searching for stuff about indentation and parens but not about "method parameters" exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961533/emacs-ruby-method-parameter-indentation

Answer (score 1):

`ruby-deep-indent-paren` and related vars have no effect for me because `ruby-use-smie` is `t`.  Setting both to `nil` didn't seem to help either :-(

But switching to [enh-ruby-mode](https://github.com/zenspider/enhanced-ruby-mode#synopsis), it's working!

- Setting `enh-ruby-deep-indent-paren` to `nil` had an effect.
- Setting `enh-ruby-bounce-deep-indent` to `t` allows me to press Tab again to toggle between the styles!

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's trying to line up the args in a multi-line list of parenthesized arguments, like:

```
function_call (arg1,
               arg2);
```

Setting the `ruby-deep-indent-paren` to nil as above changes the behvaior to the annoying double-indenting for mixed braces, e.g.:

```
if (cond) then
  do_stuff
end
function_call (&proc {
    do_stuff
  })
```

The indenting wierdness is really bothering me. I edited Mats' original ruby-mode.el code to try and indent more sanely. But I can't get it cleaned up for the life of me.