# Emacs Ruby method parameter indentation

Tags: ruby, emacs, code-formatting

I want to make emacs indent ruby method calls like:

```
foo(
  :blah => 'bar',
  :shibby => 'baz'
)
```

The closest I can get is:

```
foo(
  :blah => 'bar',
  :shibby => 'baz'
  )
```

This is using ruby-deep-indent-paren, ruby-deep-indent-paren-style, ruby-deep-arglist all set to nil.

Hashes indent how I like... if I could just make method calls indent like hashes I would be happy.  Any ideas?

Comment: +1, I still haven't figured out how to fix that closing paren alignment neither.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Dmitry Gutov](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.ruby.rails/422) has posted [this fix](https://gist.github.com/1274520), using advice, which seems to work:

```lisp
(defadvice ruby-indent-line (after unindent-closing-paren activate)
  (let ((column (current-column))
        indent offset)
    (save-excursion
      (back-to-indentation)
      (let ((state (syntax-ppss)))
        (setq offset (- column (current-column)))
        (when (and (eq (char-after) ?\))
                   (not (zerop (car state))))
          (goto-char (cadr state))
          (setq indent (current-indentation)))))
    (when indent
      (indent-line-to indent)
      (when (> offset 0) (forward-char offset)))))
```

Answer (score 6):

Ruby indentation in the current Emacs trunk (to be released as 24.4) works like you're asking without any additional tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a key sequence like C-c o, that you could press with the cursor on that closing paren that would show what variable is used and let you type in a new value (like 0 or +). Try that!